# Android - Params inside bundle using EXTRA_HEADERS through CustomTabs intent, are not received/readed by Google Chrome after app update in Play Store

Tags: android, chrome-custom-tabs, webintents, android-customtabs

Google Chrome was upgraded in Play Store to 83.0.4103.106 version (https://chromereleases.googleblog.com/2020/06/stable-channel-update-for-desktop_15.html). In there, Google team did some enforcements to avoid JS injection. My android app uses CustomTabs to open some URLs, I use a Bundle with `Browser.EXTRA_HEADERS` to add one key-value pair to the headers request, this header is mandatory to open correctly the URLs. The bundle is added to the `customTabsIntent.intent`. In prior versions to 83, the app works as expected but now, with that upgrade, it seems like Google Chrome does not receive the header parameter I added, so the url does not load correctly. Any ideas of what I should change in the app or could be this a Google Chrome issue?

Note: That 83.0.4103.106 version for Google Chrome was release on June 15th, 2020.

**EDIT:** Google Team has answered about why they remove it:

Check full answer [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1101458&q=android%20EXTRA_HEADERS&can=2)

> This is the result of a security fix [1] - basically since we don't know that the app launching a CCT is made by the same developer as the website, it technically counts as cross origin. Because of this we restricted the headers that could be set through the Browser.EXTRA_HEADERS to those on the CORS safelist...

Comment: A question: do you control the URLs being opened inside the app?

Answer (score 0):

Adding custom headers was removed due to being a vulnerability. CORS safe-listed request headers are still supported. You can read more about this change here: http://crbug.com/873178